# Setting internal prototype

Tags: javascript

Is there any possible way to change the prototype of an instance without using the `__proto__` property?

I've came up with this:

```
x=new String();
y=new Array();
Object.setPrototypeOf(x,y.__proto__)
```

But this still uses `__proto__`.

Comment: Which environment gives you `Object.setPrototypeOf()`?

Comment: @alex I got a link [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) .Under the description section u can check

Comment: In the link you provided it says `Actually it is not possible to change the prototype of an instance without using the __proto__ property`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like:

```
function object(o) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
}

x = object(y);
```

Taken from *JavaScript Patterns* by Stoyan Stefanov

Comment: That's not changing the existing prototype chain though, that's creating a new object which its prototype set to its argument.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an object, you can't change its [[Prototype]] link without using the `__proto__` property.

Your example doesn't make sense from a practicality perspective. If you want to use either `String` or `Array`'s methods on the other, simply call them and set their ThisBinding, or assign them as you need them.

However, you *could* create new objects of which their [[Prototype]] link points to another.

```
var obj = Object.create(String.prototype);
```

This of course doesn't modify the original object.